# how we can create an exe file to install jasper report server with our reports and database?

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I am trying to create an exe file to install jasper report server with our reports and database. I just want to know how could be integrate my reports and database with jasper server exe file.

Comment: Hi Alex do u have any idea how i can get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the import and export tools for jasper server to get your reports from e.g. development into production. This is all documented in the books.

You can bundle the installer for jasper and your database, the database server, the database dump with the reports and anything else you need as well as a script that installs it all together into a bundle. E.g. using Apache Maven with the app-assembler plugin. There are too many different ways to do it. You are basically automating the install and that would vary a LOT based on your needs. E.g. you could also look at puppet or chef or all sorts of installer solutions.

The best example is probably the JasperServer installer itself with the sample reports.. you could just take that and modify it to suit your needs (caveat... not sure about the license situation for doing that..).

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have used import and export tools for jasper but i want to create a separate .exe file with our demo report and database as "Jasperreportserver-cp-4.0.1.exe". How can i do that?

Comment: Thanks for updating answer, Now i can create a installer with our database and demo reports using NSIS installer.